# How can I set all text color in react components?

Tags: reactjs

I have multiple components in react project and What I'm trying to do is set all the text on the page to white .

This is the index.css file :

```
:root {
    color: white !important;
}
```

But it's not working so How can I set every text rendered on the page to white ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
*{
    color: white !important;
}
```

Try this one.